# Handling views with AngularJS and node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, user-interface, routes

I have a question. What is the correct way to manage views in AngularJS for client side and node for server side app?

I'm developing simple chat application with login/register functionality with two html files - 'index.html' with login/register form and 'chat.html' with chat window etc. Switching between those two should be done by node like this (authentication isn't implemented yet):

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.resolve('../client/')));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/html/index.html'));
});

app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('../client/html/chat.html'));
});
```

or by angular? I'm pretty confused. Please help.

EDIT:
I have one more question. What is correct way to do the authentication here? User data should be send by angular as jsons to server, or is it better to manage it on html level with 'form' element?

Comment: Multiple questions are a bad choice. You should read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok, i will adhere to this next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well from what i'm seeing things, you're not taking full use of the SPA thing with Angular, so the correct way to do it is like the following:
I you may allow me to alter you code a bit i would do it like the this

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
const path = require('path');

//Serving here your whole public or dist files.
app.use("/", express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../dist/')));

//Instead of returning pages you return Json data. 
app.get('/chat', function (req, res) {

});
```

The main idea is to send only one index.html file, this one will host your AngularJS code and Front End routes (ng-router/ui-router) one beside to all the fragments and controller/factories ...

Now regarding securing your routes, or mainly here since you need to switch your Express routes from serving Html files to serving Json data, we will secure the data roues, there's no better solution than using [Passport](http://passportjs.org/)
And implement one of the Strategies found there.

With [Passport](http://passportjs.org/) you can implement Json Web Token and Social login and many other more, and to add them to your Routes you will need simply to the following:

```
app.get('/chat', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
        session: false
}), (req, res) => {

});
```

It will act simply as an express middleware and if it will find that your request obbies the security rules that you've created it will pass it or other it will give your 403 unauthorized response.

I think this wrap up everything you need.

Comment: Ok, so i only return html on one route: "/" and the chat view is accessed through calling get request on "/chat" with angular, what should be done after authenticating the user earlier?

Comment: Well typically it's the case, you want to return just one index.html within it your Angularjs routes, so inside your ui.router or ng-router routes you will put there the /chat route which ones call will get the data from you nodejs routes which will be secured.

Comment: But the view switching should be done by angular, right?

Comment: Of course via your angular routes, if this answer helped you give it a vote so it can help others :)

Comment: I think i get it know. Thanks.